# Kineticjs group begins to drag when its resized to minimum size

Tags: kineticjs

I have a Kineticjs canvas with one layer on it.  The layer has a group.  The group has four anchors and an image.  I used the code from the resizing tutorial (http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) with some modifications.  I wanted to enforce a minimun size (50 x 50px).  When the user drags one of the resizing anchors (topLeft or bottomRight), once its reaches the minimum size, the whole group begins to drag.  This only happens with the topLeft anchor.  The bottomRight behaves as expected (when it reaches the minimum size, it stops and the group doesn't drag).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is the code I am using:

**The selector that calls resizingModeOn()**

```
$('.someSelector').on('click', function() {
              // created a layer, created an image...

              // add the new layer to the stage,
              // add the group to the layer,
              // add the large image to the group
              group.add(image);
              newLayer.add(group);
              stage.add(newLayer);
              addAnchor(group, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
              addAnchor(group, image.getWidth(), 0, 'topRight');
              addAnchor(group, 0, image.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft');
              addAnchor(group, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 'bottomRight');

              // turn on resizing mode
              resizingModeOn(group);
        };


function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
  var stage = group.getStage();
  var layer = group.getLayer();

  var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        stroke: '#666',
        strokeWidth: 2,
        radius: 8,
        name: name,
        dragOnTop: false
  });


  anchor.on('dragend', function() {
        group.setDraggable(true);
        layer.draw();
  });

  anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function() {
        group.setDraggable(false);
        this.moveToTop();
  });

  // add hover styling
  anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
        var layer = this.getLayer();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        this.setStrokeWidth(4);
        layer.draw();
  });

  anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
        var layer = this.getLayer();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        this.setStrokeWidth(2);
        layer.draw();
  });

  group.add(anchor);
  //anchor.hide();
}
```

**This turns on the resizing anchors (topLeft, bottomRight)**

```
function resizingModeOn(group) {

  // iterate through the anchors and set them
  var layer = group.getLayer();
  var anchors = group.getChildren();
  for (n = 0; n < anchors.length; n++) {
        switch(anchors[n].getName()) {

              // only the topLeft and bottom Right buttons are used for resizing
              case 'topLeft':
              case 'bottomRight':
                    anchors[n].setFill('#ddd');
                    anchors[n].setDraggable('true');

                    anchors[n].on('dragmove', function() {
                          update(this);
                          layer.draw();
                    });
                    break;

              // the topRight button is a delete/exit button
              case 'topRight':
                    anchors[n].setFill('ff0000');
                    anchors[n].setDraggable(false);
                    break;
              case 'bottomLeft':
                    anchors[n].setFill('0000ff');
                    anchors[n].setDraggable(false);
                    break;
              default:
                    break;
        }
  }
}
```

**The update function to update anchor positions**

```
function update(activeAnchor) {
  var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

  var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
  var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
  var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
  var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
  var image = group.get('.image')[0];

  var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
  var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

  // update anchor positions
  switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
        case 'topLeft':
              topRight.setY(anchorY);
              bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
        break;
        case 'topRight':
              topLeft.setY(anchorY);
              bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
        break;
        case 'bottomRight':
              bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
              topRight.setX(anchorX);
        break;
        case 'bottomLeft':
              bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
              topLeft.setX(anchorX);
        break;
  }

  // enforces a minimum size
  if (topRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + 50) {
        topRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
  }
  if (bottomRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + 50) {
        bottomRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
  }
  if (bottomRight.getY() < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
        bottomRight.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
  }
  if (bottomLeft.getY() < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
        bottomLeft.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
  }


  // enforces a minimum size
  var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
  var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();

  // Update handle positions to reflect new image dimensions
  topLeft.setPosition(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());
  topRight.setPosition(topRight.getX(), topRight.getY());
  bottomRight.setPosition(bottomRight.getX(), bottomRight.getY());
  bottomLeft.setPosition(bottomLeft.getX(), bottomLeft.getY());
  image.setPosition(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY());

  if(width && height) {
        image.setSize(width, height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but you're missing some "enforcement" on the anchors to completely restrict resizing/dragging the image.

**In your example:**

```
// enforces a minimum size
if (topRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + 50) {
      topRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
}
if (bottomRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + 50) {
      bottomRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
}
if (bottomRight.getY() < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
      bottomRight.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
}
if (bottomLeft.getY() < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
      bottomLeft.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
}
```

Only your `bottomRight` anchor is fully enforced through `(x,y)`. Then you only enforce the **x** value for `topRight`, and the **y** value for `bottomLeft`. What about the rest? You need to enforce `(x,y)` for all four corners.

Note: This is why the image is **"dragging when resized to minimum size"**. It's because the image position is being updated to the `topLeft` position, but the **x** or **y** value was not enforced for every anchor so the code moves all the anchors and the image together, simulating a "dragging" effect.

**This is how I did it** with just a few edits to the [tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/):

```
    function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var image = group.get('.image')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                if (anchorX > topRight.getX() - 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setX(topRight.getX() - 50);
                    bottomLeft.setX(topRight.getX() - 50);
                }
                if (anchorY > bottomLeft.getY() - 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setY(bottomLeft.getY() - 50);
                    topRight.setY(bottomLeft.getY() - 50);
                }
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                if (anchorX < topLeft.getX() + 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
                    bottomRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + 50);
                }
                if (anchorY > bottomLeft.getY() - 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setY(bottomLeft.getY() - 50);
                    topLeft.setY(bottomLeft.getY() - 50);
                }
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                if (anchorX < bottomLeft.getX() + 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setX(bottomLeft.getX() + 50);
                    topRight.setX(bottomLeft.getX() + 50);
                }
                if (anchorY < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
                    bottomLeft.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
                }
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                if (anchorX > topRight.getX() - 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setX(topRight.getX() - 50);
                    topLeft.setX(topRight.getX() - 50);
                }
                if (anchorY < topLeft.getY() + 50) {
                    activeAnchor.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
                    bottomRight.setY(topLeft.getY() + 50);
                }
                break;
        }

        image.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height) {
            image.setSize(width, height);
        }
    }
```

It's a bit different from your approach, but it's the same idea and it works. You should be able to see what I mean and adapt it to your code. Good luck!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/aFhrf/)